# Graphics/Mesh scale and anchor with different screen resolution

Tags: unity, mobile

I wanted to ask if there is a recommended approach to designing graphics that **adapt** and **anchor** to the different resolutions/aspect ratios found on different mobile devices (especially considering the safe area).

Unity already provides with uGUI via the **Canvas Scaler** component the ability to scale (**Scale with Screen Size**) the elements of the UI.

Regarding the scaling, according to the following answer in the comment below of [DMGregory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPNPk.png) there should be no problem, but regarding the positioning yes.

Is there an anchoring system similar to the one provided by uGUI or do I have to calculate it manually?

Look at examples below where a quad is positioned in the bottom-right corner at (`Vector3(9.36999989,-4.86999989,-0.119999997)`)

**IPHONE 6 -> RES 1334 x 750 ratio 1.77**
[image]

**IPHONE 8 PLUS -> RES 1920 x 1080 ratio 1.77**
(This is not visible but the quad has been scaled up a bit and the quad position is still at the same place).

[image]

**IPHONE 13 PRO MAX -> RES 2778 x 1284 ratio 2.16**
(The quad is not in the correct position and it's out of the safe area)
[image]**

**IPAD 5TH Gen. -> RES 2048 x 1536 ratio 1.33**
(The quad is totally disappeared)

[image]

Ultimately I try to explain better my goal: I would like the graphic elements to be always positioned or anchored correctly taking into account the different resolution and/or aspcet ratio (and safe area) of mobile devices. All this leaving to the graphic engine the burden of automatically scaling the graphic elements?
Thank you.

Comment: If you're only looking at UI, you should definitely not be changing the camera FOV to make the UI fit on the screen. Use the RectTransform layout options to ensure your UI layout adapts to the screen. For example, if something should be aligned to the bottom-left of the screen, anchor it to the bottom-left of the screen.

Comment: @DMGregory, I edited my question hoping now it's a bit clearer...

Comment: Much clearer, thank you. If you want to anchor an element to the corner of the screen, the UI system is the most natural way to do that. Is there a reason why this quad cannot be an image in your Canvas hierarchy instead?

Comment: Thank you for the support. The reason is that the game objects (I mean meshes in the case of 3D games or sprites for 2D games) I would like to keep them separate from the UI objects. It seems like a constraint, for example, to have to manipulate the position of a mesh via a RectTransform, and so on for other cases.  This is a simple case: a Quad that could be an Image. But for a complex mesh? I don't think that's a feasible solution, do you?